# Putting an image in a div constant in place over wordpress site

Tags: css, wordpress, html

I have a WP site that i am trying to pimp a little.

It will be a place to check out iPhone accesories and i want it to have the iphone look.

I have made a background that i am pleased with but i want to put the background picture over the whole page so the "frame" of the iphone lookalike thing i´ve done is visible all the time and the content of the WP gos under it when scrolled.

My wp is here:

http://www.metalagency.com

and the image that i want to be on top is here:

http://www.metalagency.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/testdiv.png

The white section of the image is transparent so i want the wp site to visible in that area.

Am i making any sense here?

Sorry if it is a stupid q but i dont seem to find any answer anywhere on this.

I understand that i need to do some css styling but i am not sure where to put it.

Pls help a slow Swede....

Thanx.

//R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bookmarklet preview: open your page, copy into location bar, press enter:

```
javascript:sa=document.styleSheets;sa[sa.length-1].insertRule('#page { background: transparent; height: 700px; overflow: scroll; }');
```

You should create a simple child theme first (if you don't want your modified twentyeleven theme overwritten by an automattic update): http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#The_required_style.css_file and put all your modifications there.

Sample style.css:

```
/*
Theme Name:     myPhoney theme
Template:       twentyeleven
*/

@import url("../twentyeleven/style.css");

#page {
  background: transparent;
  height: 700px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Ok Where do i put the css?  In the style.css?

Comment: Glad it works :) Unfortunately the default scrollbars may be ugly, so you might want to find some javascript solution which simulates iOS-like scrollbars.

Comment: Do you know how i could get the whole page further down?  So the meny is like 10-15px lower?

Comment: Put `margin-top: 15px` or `padding-top: 10px` into the `#page {...}` rule.

Comment: Thank you sir and have a really pleasant day!

Comment: Thanks :) BTW, its dark night out there (probably in Sweden too :)